# SQL Query to select 2nd occurrence

Tags: sql

I want to write an SQL query to extract the average review length of the 2nd review of each reviewer with at least 2 reviews.

The review table has the following columns:
ListingID, ID, Reviewer_ID, Reviewer_Name, Comments.

I have been able to write this query below to count the review length:

```
Select LISTING_ID,REVIEWER_NAME,REVIEWER_ID, COMMENTS,
  length(COMMENTS) - length(replace(COMMENTS, ' ', '')) + 1 NumbofWords
from "SQL_TEST"."AIRBNB_DATA"."REVIEWS"
```

Please, can you help me include the query for 2nd review of each reviewer with at least 2 reviews?

I will appreciate your assistance.

```
Select LISTING_ID,REVIEWER_NAME,REVIEWER_ID, COMMENTS,
  length(COMMENTS) - length(replace(COMMENTS, ' ', '')) + 1 NumbofWords
from "SQL_TEST"."AIRBNB_DATA"."REVIEWS"
```

I want to write an SQL query to extract the average review length of the 2nd review of each reviewer with at least 2 reviews.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text - not images. And also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: please see sample table: ReviewID Listing_id ReviewLenght Reviewer
1 1230 3 sdf
2 3450 35 sgr
3 4450 45 tyu
4 3560 67 gdh
5 4560 78 gdj
6 4450 65 dgj
7 4450 32 bhf
8 3560 3 kkh
9 1230 6 dtg
10 3430 7 cgfh
11 4450 13 kld
12 1230 69 dhh
13 4560 86 dch

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this problem using row_number() by partition:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    ListingID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Reviewer_ID INT,
    Reviewer_Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Comments NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Reviewer_ID,Reviewer_Name,Comments) VALUES
(1,'kyle','comment 1'),
(1,'kyle','comment 2'),
(2,'steve','comment 1'),
(3,'karen','comment 1'),
(3,'karen','comment 2')

SELECT ListingID,Reviewer_Name,Reviewer_ID,Comments,LEN(Comments) - LEN(REPLACE(Comments, ' ', '')) + 1 AS NumberOfWords FROM @temp
WHERE ListingID IN
(
    SELECT ListingID FROM
    (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Reviewer_ID ORDER BY ListingID) row_num FROM @temp
    ) t1 WHERE row_num = 2
)
```

This insures that I only get the 2nd comment and not the first nor the third and after.

OUTPUT:

```
ListingID   Reviewer_Name   Reviewer_ID Comments    NumberOfWords
2           kyle            1           comment 2   2
5           karen           3           comment 2   2
```

Comment: Looks right to me. Why the extra level of nesting though? And make sure to cast the expression to decimal type before computing an average.

Comment: ReviewID Listing_id ReviewLenght Reviewer
1 1230 3 sdf
2 3450 35 sgr
3 4450 45 tyu
4 3560 67 gdh
5 4560 78 gdj
6 4450 65 dgj
7 4450 32 bhf
8 3560 3 kkh
9 1230 6 dtg
10 3430 7 cgfh
11 4450 13 kld
12 1230 69 dhh
13 4560 86 dch